# Rails Arel joins with where condition on joined table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm trying to convert the following Rails where clause to use Arel, mostly to take advantage of the `or` method that Arel provides.

Post model

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

User model

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end
```

I'm looking for posts posted by Mark.

This is the Rails Query:

```
Post.joins(:user).where(users: { first_name: 'Mark' })
```

I need to convert this query with Arel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
# Generate Arel tables for both
posts = Arel::Table.new(:posts)
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)

# Make a join and add a where clause
posts.join(:users).on(posts[:user_id].eq(users[:id])).where(users[:first_name].eq('Mark'))
```

Comment: are you sure this would help ? I got error on this : undefined method `joins' for #<Arel::Table:>

Comment: @AfsaneFadaei correct, there's no such a method as `joins`, replaced it with `join`

Answer (score 0):

If you only need Arel for the where part (not for the join), I think this would be a better solution (will wield Activerecord results):

```
Post.joins(:user).where(User.arel_table[:first_name].eq('Mark'))
```

Comment: Then why isn't `Post.joins(:user).where('users.first_name = ?', 'Mark')` better? ActiveRecord all the way

Comment: @kiddorails because this way you can use `.or` and other methods provided by Arel, while still handling Activerecord results easily

Comment: I'm aware that those are the benefits of ARE, in general; but it begs no use case in this particular query.