# How to keep one table's data in another while being updated without association in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to find the best approach more than any thing by this question.
I have two models :

**Letter.rb**

```
class Letter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trackings,dependent: :destroy
end
```

Letter columns:
   sub, 
   title

**Tracking.rb**

```
class Tracking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :letter
end
```

Tracking Columns:
    number,
    date

I have a table like this in view containing these columns:

**Trackings**

```
Tracking_id / number / date / letter_id / sub / title
```

I want to search in **Trackings** via arel and return Trackings records as the search results.The search is multiple, for instance first search based on number and then search the results again based on title but the problem is that I can't search the associations.

I have a solution. I can keep the letters data as new columns in Trackings but if I update the letter somewhere else these data are not going to be updated so I can run a job to update all the letter data in existing Trackings. I want to know that is there any better idea to cover this problem ? or this solution suffices ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `Tracking` class does not seem to have a table reference to `Letter` shouldn't there be a `letter_id` column in the table for reference? Also not sure why you need `Arel` for this as the search logic is not very complex (and trust me I am a huge advocate of `Arel` when it is called for)

Comment: @engineersmnky Because it is a complicated multi search and sort action which is inevitable to use Arel. The Tracking table contains letter_id .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
Tracking.includes(:letter).where(number: 1234, letters: {title: 'Hello'})
```

or if you need more control over the search query:

```
Tracking
  .joins(:letter)
  .where('trackings.number like :query OR letters.title like :query', query: "%{search_term}%")
```

(you can add more conditions as you like)

This will INNER JOIN `Letter` and `Tracking` on the DB and allow you to query columns from both tables in one statement. 
This assumes that every `Tracking` has a `Letter`.
Like this the data can stay where it is and where it belongs. In its tables.

Comment: The second option is not valid as it stands and will not create a LEFT OUTER JOIN if you change it to a string without adding `references(:letters)`

Comment: Well kind of. The first is still a valid LEFT OUTER JOIN and the second is still not valid and should be `.where("trackings.number like :query OR letters.title like :query", query: "%{search_term}%")` note the quotes. it would have been equally as valid to leave the explanation of LEFT OUTER JOIN and change the example to `Tracking.includes(:letter).references(:letters)
  .where("trackings.number like :query OR letters.title like :query", query: "%{search_term}%")`

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the quotes. :-(
I think the INNER JOIN is OK, given the relationships and assuming that there is always a Letter. Let's see if the OP has some feedback.

Comment: @engineersmnky it's ok bu I'm working with arel and need something like what this post said:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39236293/rails-arel-joins-with-where-condition-on-joined-table

Comment: I used this differently and my open issue solved . The first solution helped me.thank you all.

Comment: @AfsaneFadel there is no complexity in your question and no complexity in the other post mentioned. Arel is overkill unless you have completely understated your question.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes my question is just an example to represent my actual problem I couldn't share the actual code so I simplified it . thank you for putting time on this

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep the letters data as new columns in Trackings table. You can join both the table and fetch data based on your search query.

```
Tracking.joins(:letter).where("letters.sub like :search or letters.title like :search or trackings.number like :search", search: "%#{SEARCH_QUERY}%")
```

This will **JOIN** the `letters` and `trackings` table and allow the query to fetch data from both the tables.